# Are bounded sequences always strictly less than some fixed number $M$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Definition: A sequence $(x_n)$ is
>    *bounded* if there exists a number $M \gt 0$ such that $ \left| x_{n}
>  \right| \leq M$ for all $n \in
>  \mathbb{N}$.

Question: Is there any reason why one can't replace $ \left| x_{n} \right| \leq M$ with the strict inequality $ \left| x_{n} \right| < M$? Since $M$ is a fixed number it seems that $1$ could always be added to make the inequality strict, but maybe I am missing something... If I am right, and the inequality can always be strict, then why didn't they write it that way in the first place?

Comment: You want to allow yourself the benefit of a "maximal element" as the bound, which will result a weak inequality.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is: yes.The answer to the first question in the post is: no. The answer to the second question in the post is: they could have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are absolutely right, one could also write "there exists $M$ such that $|x_n| < M$ for all $n$"; the two statements are equivalent.  But if they had written it that way, you'd be asking why they didn't write "$x_n \le M$"...

There's a slight advantage to writing $\le$: if the sequence is bounded, then there is always a *smallest* $M$ such that $|x_n| \le M$ for all $n$.  (Namely, $M = \sup_n |x_n|$.)  But there may not be a smallest $M$ such that $|x_n| < M$ for all $n$.  (Consider the constant sequence $x_n = 0$...)

Comment: ok that totally makes sense, thank you for this answer.